# Laptop works fine with ac adapter, hangs after login screen using battery

Tags: 10.10, laptop, login-screen, battery

I did an *Ubuntu 10.10 Desktop Edition* clean install (amd64 version) on a notebook *Medion Akoya E1311*. **With AC adapter everything works fine, but using battery, it hangs after login screen**.

I can type login, password too, and I can press login button. But then I can see mouse cursor and lower task bar, not upper, and nothing works. The only thing I can do is login on a terminal with *ctrl+alt+F1*, this is ok.

Nothing seems alive on Gnome except mouse cursor. The only thing I did after Ubuntu fresh install was donwloading driver for RTL8191SE from Realtek web, because WiFi didn't work, now works fine, with ac adapter of course.

Hardware is a Notebook Medion Akoya E1311

- AMD Sempron 210U
- 1 GB DDR2
- ATI RS690M (Radeon X1200 Series)
- Western Digital 160GB
- wireless RTL8191SEvB
- ethernet RTL8101E/RTL8102E

Comment: Does it work in windows? or with an Ubuntu liveCD? This is a very strange problem to have and sounds very much like a hardware issue. But I'd like to see if you can test it.

Comment: Hi, I am running into similar problem, it hangs right after I put in password, click the log-in button, showing the beautiful color background, mouse pointer is ok to move around, but the desktop just failed to boot!

It's a clean install, I am using Toshiba Satellite A105-S2071 laptop with 2GB mem...

I wonder if you have yours fix yet? and what seems to be the problem?

P.S. I am quite new to Ubuntu, on this laptop, I have Windows XP and Oracle Enterprise Linux installed also, and they all running smoothly!

Comment: Similar problem here. I am using a cheap Dell 1014 laptop. This is still happening after upgrading to 11.04. And this is on a BRAND NEW laptop.

Comment: try disabling the wireless while plugged in and the unplug it and reboot see what happens

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is no visible activity or information added to it for several months. I have flagged a moderator and am voting for it to be closed. If you feel that the question is not abandoned and that you still suffer from this issue please flag a moderator so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

Well for anyone using 11.04, Natty is having problems with slightly older hardware running the new Unity desktop, as for 10.10, i can't say what the problem is, I have a 7 year old PC that had 10.10 and it runs WONDERFULLY! It may be that the battery is having to work to hard to start everything up in Ubuntu, go to Preferences>Startup Applications, and disable anything that you don't need to immediately have when using Ubuntu, also you could try (on battery) on the logon screen, after you have clicked your username, there should be a little box at the bottom with the phrase "Ubuntu Desktop" or something like that (In 11.04,default is Unity), click the arrow to reveal a pop-up menu, and select the Ubuntu Desktop (recovery) option, or whichever one has a (recovery) tag next to it, try to log on using that desktop, and if it works, check the basic power managing settings (Preferences>Power Management) and check the settings regarding "On battery" Hope this helps!!